# Accessing a returned value from a different case

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, return-value, scope

Hi It's the 3rd time i'm posting this question on this forum and up to now no one has been capable to enlighten me about this situation.

I only pasted the code that matters here and will try to explain in as best as I can ...

Methods:

1. showMenu(in) - show's a menu list which also calls choice(in)
2. choice(in) - accepts an in input through -> getNumber(in)
3. getNumber(in) - is the number returned and now selects the correct case

---

Now I'm only dealing with case 1: and case 2:

case 1:

1. String clef = assigned return value from saisirClef(in)
2. saisirClef(in); is the method that returns the string after completing logic
3. showMenu(in) is needed so I can now pick a different case

case 2: 
Simple I'm trying to access the String after it has been completed in case 1;
If Not then I should go through Case 1

Can this be done ?
I feel like everytime it gets passed the break all my variables dissapear is this normal ?

How can I do this ?

```
public static void choice(Scanner in){

    switch(getNumber(in)){
        case 1:
            String clef = saisirClef(in);
            showMenu(in);
            break;
        case 2:
            if(clef.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("Erreur : Aucune clef n’a été saisie.");
                saisirClef(in);
            }
            else{
                afficherClef(clef);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            chiffrerFichier();
            break;
        case 4:
            dechiffrerFichier();
            break;
        case 5:
            quitApplication();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Default");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static String clef = null;

public static void choice(Scanner in){

    switch(getNumber(in)){
        case 1:
            clef = saisirClef(in);
            showMenu(in);
            break;
        case 2:
            if(clef == null || clef.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("Erreur : Aucune clef n’a été saisie.");
                clef = saisirClef(in);
            }
            else{
                afficherClef(clef);
            }
            break;
                    // ...
    }
```

Comment: Why do you add `clef = null;` inside the if statement for case 2 ?

Comment: Because if you dont, and you get 1, 2, 2, you will re-saisirClef again. If that is desired behaviour, then just remove the `clef = null;`.

Comment: actually the desied behavior is to store the `clef = saisirClef(in);` since saisirClef will return a string after going throught series of tests ... still not working as desired ... but improved a bit

Comment: I just edited my answer to accomodate for the information you gave. Try that, please.

Comment: Just tried it ... and it falls into `Erreur : Aucune clef n’a été saisie.
Saisir la clef secrète  :` Which is wrong if I go through case 1 and save the key ,,, then the menu pops up again and now I go through case 2 and it shows as empty ... is it possible because I never reached the break in case 1 ?

Comment: Aw man. Sorry. Variables do not survive the execution scope of the method, of course. I just edited my answer. Again.

Comment: I know that would be ideal but I forget to mention ... I am not allowed to use any global variables

Comment: Do you mean static member variables? Because there are no global variables in java.

Comment: i guess doing something like `public final String = null;` so that would be a CONSTANT ?